# Sqlite database in iOS on termination

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

I have build an application integrated with Sq-lite database, the application works as expected , but when i terminate the application from the device, the database file deleted and the application lose all the needed data !!

i appreciate any help regarding a way i can use to save the database file after terminate the application.

Comment: Database file cannot be deleted until you delete it..

Comment: the application read all needed data from SQLite database successfully until, but after terminate the app, the app can't read anything !!

Comment: Did u check the simulator path or the devices document folder for the .sqlite file?

Comment: Do you have save mechanism in your applicationWillTerminate method as I mentioned below?

Comment: Do you use Core Data to manage your database? It is not clear from your question whether you use Core Data which is using Sqlite for persistence or you somehow manage for your own the Sqlite db handling?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly making a call to save your data before closing your app in your *AppDelegate.m*. This should solve your problem.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            // manage db save error
        }
    }
}
```

Pls not if the save is more than 5 sec (eg. because too many rows to persist, or complex db structure) , then you can use *beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler* to request background execution time from ios in a different thread for saving your data.